# AngularJS multiple file upload with crop

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

In [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rw6q9/1121/) example first file upload crop is working but second file upload is not working.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngImgCrop']);
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myImage='';
  $scope.myCroppedImage='';
  var handleFileSelect=function(evt) {
    var file=evt.currentTarget.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (evt) {
      $scope.$apply(function($scope){
        $scope.myImage=evt.target.result;
      });
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  };
  angular.element(document.querySelector('#fileInput'))
         .on('change',handleFileSelect);
});

var app1 = angular.module('app1', ['ngImgCrop']);
app1.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope) {
  $scope.myImage1='';
  $scope.myCroppedImage1='';
  var handleFileSelect1=function(evt) {
    var file1=evt.currentTarget.files[0];
    var reader1 = new FileReader();
    reader1.onload = function (evt) {
      $scope.$apply(function($scope){
        $scope.myImage1=evt.target.result;
      });
    };
    reader1.readAsDataURL(file1);
  };
  angular.element(document.querySelector('#fileInput1'))
         .on('change',handleFileSelect1);
});
```